# I need to compare files in 2 directories and be able to tell how long each set of files has been the same in Bash

Tags: bash, comparison

Basically, I have 2 copies of a set of .csv files in separate directories. 1 copy is today's data, and the other copy is yesterday's data. The script I have that makes the backup only runs once per day, so that's how often I need this to run. What I want to do is compare them to see if the files are the same, and if a set of files has been the same for 14 days, then have an email notification get sent out notifying myself and my coworkers that a particular file hasn't changed.

So, I've already got the comparison part down:

diff -sq DIR_1 DIR_2 | sort > comparison_results.txt

However, now I want to read the file and have a counter for each line, so that I know for how many days each set of files has been the same, with the output in separate columns.

Ideally, the 3 columns would be $name_of_file | are the files the same? | how many days have they been the same?

I've got a while loop started for reading each line, but I'm not sure how to progress:

while read line; do

```
    counter=0
    if [[ $line == *"not identical"* ]]
    then
        $something
    else
       (( counter += 1 ))
        $something_else
    done < comparison_results.txt
```

If necessary, I can write all this output to a file, and then read that file, and if the counter column has any 14s or higher, then send out an email notification.

Essentially my question is how to read each line and send that to a file with 3 columns, followed by an email notification if any of the files have been the same for 14 days or more?

Comment: ...but if you have an *actual question*, I'd suggest trying to extract it out and make it more clear. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and particularly http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Personally, btw, I'd consider tracking a timestamp in epoch-time for the first time two files were observed to be identical, and just checking for cases when that timestamp is more than (14*3600) seconds ago. That way you aren't dealing with a counter, and your script can be rerun a bunch of times inside the same day without breaking the logic (similarly, the logic won't be broken by skipping a day, etc).

Comment: I edited the post to help clarify the question. I only need the script to run once a day though, so I'm not sure the timestamp would be necessary. Unless of course that would be easier to handle than the counter.

Comment: Certainly easier to handle from an operational perspective. If you have an outage or a downtime window and your system misses its cronjob that day, you don't want all your counts to be off. And if you fix a bug and want to rerun with that bug fixed, you don't want things to be incremented twice. Speaking as someone who's been in this business for a while, making your scripts idempotent is generally good practice from a headache-reduction perspective.

Comment: I would write it in Qt as its got a lot more higher level tools which can be used to quickly and easily code your solution...    `QDirIterator` `QBuffer`,  `QTextStream`, `QSqlite` and `QFileInfo`  are some  tools that come to mind for solving this..  but thats if your system has Qt installed

Comment: That makes sense @CharlesDuffy

Comment: BTW -- are these files regenerated on a regular basis (or otherwise going through a process prone to munging mtimes), or is there value to only comparing them if their modification times have been updated since yesterday?

Comment: To be clear, I'm somewhat frowning on `diff -sq` -- its output is meant for human consumption, not parsing, and isn't well-defined for all possible filenames (filenames can contain newline literals, nonprintable characters, and all manner of other fun).

Comment: @mike510a, We're running redhat, but it's unlikely we have anything that didn't come packaged with the OS.

Comment: ...*however*: This question's scope is outside the realm of "answer a question about shell facilities / best practices" and getting into the area of "write my program for me", so commenting might be as far as I go here.

Comment: @mike510a, ...I'd be surprised if someone asking a shell question would be happy to write C++ instead. And as ugly as they are, the native facilities are certainly sufficient for the question at hand.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Each file pertains to a particular application that was delivered from that application team daily, which contains a list of users and what access they have in that application. Each day, the new file overwrites the old one, so each file is basically app_name_accts.csv. I've then written a script that makes a backup before we get tomorrow's data so that I have 2 days' worth of data.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  I agree,  but it was more like a `when all else fails plan`.. just in case frustration takes over down the line (as it sometimes does with BASH scripting)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I didn't mean for it to come off that way. I've been doing a lot of reading on google and other articles on here, but having difficulty finding anything relevant to my situation. I guess it really boils down to how would I use the column command to write to 3 separate columns with the data I want? From using MAN column, I believe I would need the -c argument, but I'm not sure how to get information into each column.

Comment: ...why would you try to use `column` for this job at all?

Comment: `printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' "first column" "second column" "third column"` <- write three columns.

Comment: A coworker of mine suggested it, so I was looking into how it would work, but after doing some more reading, what you suggested makes more sense.

Comment: FYI -- my answer has been under some revision for a bit, but it's currently passing my tests. Enjoy.

Comment: (...and feel free to ask if you have questions reading/following any part of it).

Comment: Thanks, I'll do some testing, and after reading through it a few times, it definitely clears up some things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a rough draft of what a function for this purpose could look like. Note that I'm only writing names (in `eval`-safe quoted form) of files that have been identical for longer than `minAge` seconds -- sending email is an exercise for the reader.

```
findConsistentlyIdenticalFiles() {
  local dirA=$1 dirB=$2 storeLoc=$3 minAge=$4
  local fnA fnB fnStore fn currentTime storedTime

  mkdir -p -- "$storeLoc" || return

  # in very new bash, faster alternative is: printf -v currentTime '%(%s)T' -1
  # ...the following command using date is the older/slower/compatible alternative:
  currentTime=$(date +%s)

  # for each file in dirA...
  while IFS= read -r -d '' fnA; do

    # strip the directory name...
    fn="${fnA#$dirA}"; fn="${fn#/}"

    # and calculate the name of a corresponding file in dirB
    fnB=${dirB}/${fn}

    # if a file in dirA doesn't exist in dirB, or the dirB copy differs, clear our flag
    if [[ ! -e $fnB ]] || ! cmp -s "$fnA" "$fnB"; then
      rm -f -- "$storeLoc/$fn"
      continue
    fi

    fnStore=$storeLoc/$fn
    if [[ -e $fnStore ]]; then
      # if we already have a marker, check whether it's over minAge seconds old
      storedTime=$(<"$fnStore")
      if (( storedTime < currentTime - minAge )); then
        printf '%q\n' "$fn"
      fi
    else
      # whereas if we don't have a marker, populate it with the current time
      mkdir -p -- "${fnStore%/*}"
      printf '%s\n' "$currentTime" >"$storeLoc/$fn"
    fi
  done < <(find "$dirA" -type f -print0)

  # ...also, prune any store contents that don't have corresponding dirA contents
  while IFS= read -r -d '' fnStore; do
    fn="${fnStore#$storeLoc}"; fn="${fn#/}"
    [[ -e $dirA/$fn ]] || rm -f -- "$fnStore"
  done < <(find "$storeLoc" -type f -print0)
}
```

Used as:

```
findConsistentlyIdenticalFiles dirA dirB .cmptimes "$(( 3600 * 14 ))"
```

Obviously, you can easily test the logic by using much smaller number of seconds (`60` to find identical files not modified for the last minute, `5` for the last 5 seconds, etc).

---

Some notes:

- Using `find -print0` emits a NUL-delimited list of filenames, and `IFS= read -r -d '' filename` reads a single name from such a NUL-delimited list. This format is guaranteed to parse correctly even with very unusual or even malicious names -- names with newlines, names containing strings that look like `diff -sq` output, etc. See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), and [UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind).
- The `< <(find ...)` syntax avoids the issue described in [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024), wherein piping from `find` into a loop creates a subshell from which changes to shell-local state can't escape.
- Format is one metadata file per content file. This makes it much easier to read, write, or update specific content rather than needing to read and write the entire file at a time.
- The syntax used to strip components from directory names (ie. `${fn#$dirA}`, `${fn#/}`) is [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).
- The quoting on the right-hand-side of assignments is present to make StackOverflow's syntax highlighting happy, and is not related to correctness.